# Replacing values in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 6 columns and 1800 rows. The data was exported from the software with results as "Yes", "No", and "-"(for unrecorded data). I want to change - to NA, Yes to 1, and No to 0. Is there a good way to do this all at once?

I tried `datap[datap=="-"] <- NA`, which changed all the values of "-" to `<NA>`. I presume this is what I want? Then when I tried `datap[datap=="No"] <- 0`, I got an error:

```
> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

And all the "No" values became NA. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: When you read in the data try adding two arguments `datap <- read.table(my_file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="-")`. Then you can replace the column values.

Comment: Change the column to `character` using `as.character` and then replace or create a new level with the replacement value before you replace.

Comment: Thanks! Pierre's answer worked, but when I changed the Yes/No to 1/0, they are characters. How do I change multiple columns to numeric, while not changing the date column? I have been changing them individually with `datap$tasked <- as.numeric(datap$tasked)`, but is there a way to change multiple at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

something like this can do:

```
x <- sample(c("Yes", "No", "-"), 7, repl=TRUE)
y1 <- c("Yes", "No", "-"); y2 <- c(1, 0, NA)
y2[match(x,y1)]
```

in `read.table()` set the parameter `read.table(..., as.is=TRUE)` or `read.table(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`